# Jvectormap error in IE7

Tags: jvectormap

I am getting this error in IE7 and same problem coming in live website (jvectormap.com/).

can anybody resolve my issue ?

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 1 Feb 2013 05:30:11 UTC

Message: Attribute only valid on v:image
Line: 7
Char: 8124
Code: 0
URI: http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js

Message: Attribute only valid on v:image
Line: 388
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://jvectormap.com/js/css3-mediaqueries.js

Comment: css3 is not supported in IE7

Comment: The funny part is they are writing "Works in all modern browsers (including IE6-8)" they missed out IE9 and calling all other(IE 6, 7, 8) "MODERN BROWSERS"

Comment: @AurA If you have a better wording you can always submit a pull-request here https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap-site (but please don't use UPPER CASE).

Comment: @user2031446 Can't reproduce this error. Are any actions required or you see the error right after load?